# Visual Studio 2013 C++ auto indenting doesn't work well

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2013

For some reason, after I type the following block in Visual Studio 2013:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    if (some_condition)
    {

    }
```

VS 2013 automatically indents the code to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
if (some_condition)
{

}
```

If I put the if between curly brackets, it formats the code correctly. This behavior is very frustrating. I don't remember having this issue in VS 2012.

If I disable auto formatting, it doesn't even put the cursor at the same indent level as the line above. Even notepad++ works better than VS.

Is there a way to fix this? Maybe to import the indenting rules from VS2012 which worked just fine?

Comment: I think my answer must be accepted answer. I just want to remind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug is fixed with VS 2013 Update 1. Try install it Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates -> Product Updates -> Update 1

Answer (score 0):

Can you change settings as below and check

> In Tool->Options->Text editor->C/C++->Format-> Indentation (un-check this option) 
>   and reformate code block once or try new code.