# Identation of nested loop in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Is it possible to change the automatic indentation of nested loops in Visual Studio 2013 for C++, the default behavior is to align them this way:

```
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
for (uint32_t j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
```

The desired behavior would be like this:

```
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
     for (uint32_t j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++)
```

Comment: Are you sure that this describes the default behaviour? I just tried, and I didn't manage to get it *not* to behave the way you want it. I also didn't find an option in **Formatting/Indentation** or **Formatting/New Lines** that would change the behaviour. Edit: that's for Visual Studio Community 2013, Update 4.

Comment: I know this isn't good stackoverflow form (this is all I seem to be able to do as a guest) and this post is really old, but in case you're still looking for an answer or someone else comes across this problem like I did, the answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491828/visual-studio-2013-c-auto-indenting-doesnt-work-well.

Comment: Per bellert3 Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2013 C++ auto indenting doesn't work well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20491828/visual-studio-2013-c-auto-indenting-doesnt-work-well)

Answer (score 0):

It works when you have a nested loop with curly braces, otherwise for one line nested loops they expect you to press enter.  I think it has to do with indenting single line nested loops not being a common practice.

Comment: Yes, it works with curly braces, but no with out them. So i suppose there isn't an option